# Why does Ask Ubuntu have elevated status in the Terms of Use?

Tags: discussion, legal

In the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal), under *Section 4. Restrictions*, it says:

> When accessing the askubuntu.com, meta.askubuntu.com, or chat.askubuntu.com sites ("AskUbuntu"), Subscriber will also abide by the most current Ubuntu Code of Conduct, which can be found at http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct, and is hereby incorporated by reference, but solely with regard to AskUbuntu.

How was Ubuntu able to achieve this level of mojo?

Asking with tongue firmly planted in cheek, but... just as an example, could I get a similar shout-out for [The Lounge](http://loungecpp.net/w/Newbie_hints), the best chat room on the planet?

What about a "Code of Conduct" for [my other favorite SE website about the ultimate software silver bullet, the one ring to rule them all]?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We (the Stack Exchange Network) have our own "code of conduct" of sorts which is outlined in our [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service). But Canonical (Ubuntu) also has its own code of conduct that they expect their partners and participants to adhere to.

We get approached a lot for partnerships like this, but they don’t usually go anywhere because we require ceding so much control back to the community. Ubuntu was that *rare* exception where our values and end-goals aligned so ideally. In growing that (official) partnership, we wanted to assure (on both ends) that both our communities would uphold the values of *both* organizations. So it was important to the Canonical organization (and to us) that the users of that site be made explicitly aware of their code of conduct.

We were only too happy to oblige.